# Play full Mc in a single key press

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

First, sorry to ask this silly question (I am new in AS3). I wasted more then 2 weeks on this problem, and am now posting it here.

I am making a hero move with the keyboard. I have three animations.

1. Standby mode
2. walk front
3. walk behind

It's working well so far, but the problem I'm facing in jumping the player is having to hold down the key to jump. I don't want the player to be required to hold the key to perform jumping. 
So I want to play the full MovieClip with one key press, and honestly I don't know which function I have to use or how to do it.

[Here is the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4vnFn0J42xSmVNei13Q216MXc/view?usp=sharing), and here is my code

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

kim.gotoAndStop("kim Stand");

var grav:int = 0;
var floor = 450;
var dPressed:Boolean = false;
var aPressed:Boolean = false;
var jumping:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , keyDownHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , KeyUpHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , gameLoop);

function keyDownHandaler(Devent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            dPressed = true;
        }
    else if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        {
            aPressed = true;
        }
    else if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.W && !jumping)
        {
            jumping = true;
        }
}

function KeyUpHandaler (Uevent:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if (Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            dPressed = false;
            kim.gotoAndStop("kim Stand");
        }
    else if(Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
            aPressed = false;
            kim.gotoAndStop("kim Stand");
    }

    else if(Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
    {
            jumping = false;
            kim.gotoAndStop("kim Stand");
    }


}

function gameLoop(Levent:Event):void
{
    if (dPressed)
        {
            kim.x += 5;

            kim.gotoAndStop("kim Move Right");
        }
    else if(aPressed)
        {
            kim.x -= 5;
            kim.gotoAndStop("kim Move Left");
        }

    else if(jumping)
        {
            kim.gotoAndStop("kim Jump");
            kim.y -= 10;

        }

    gravity();

}

function gravity ():void
    {
        kim.y += grav;
        if (kim.y+kim.height/2 <floor){
            grav++;
        }

        else {
            grav = 0;
            kim.y = floor - kim.height/2 ;

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try state based logic.  The keyboard events set it, and the actions for updating the character are handled separately in your `gameLoop()`.  The last piece of the puzzle would be to update your state when you recognize you've landed (something that happens not from keyboard interaction, but rather from your gravity function).

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

var grav:int = 0;
var floor = 450;
var state:String = "stand";

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , keyHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , keyHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , gameLoop);

function keyHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case Keyboard.D:
            state = (e.type == "keyDown") ? "right" : "stand";
            break;
        case Keyboard.A:
            state = (e.type == "keyDown") ? "left" : "stand";
            break;
        case Keyboard.W:
            state = (e.type == "keyDown") ? "jumping" : "falling";
            break;
    }
}

function gameLoop(Levent:Event):void {  
    switch (state) {
        case "stand":
            kim.gotoAndStop("kim Stand");
            break;
        case "right":
            kim.x += 5;
            kim.gotoAndStop("kim Move Right");
            break;
        case "left":
            kim.x -= 5;
            kim.gotoAndStop("kim Move Left");
            break;
        case "jumping":
            kim.y -= 10;
            kim.gotoAndStop("kim Jump");
            break;
        case "falling":
            kim.gotoAndStop("kim Jump");
            break;
    }

    gravity();
}

function gravity ():void {
    kim.y += grav;
    if (kim.y + kim.height/2 < floor) {
        grav++;
    } else {
        grav = 0;
        kim.y = floor - kim.height/2;

        if (state == "falling") {
            state = "stand"
        }
    }
}
```